# gnu parallel processing multiple files on various instances

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I want to process many files on many database instances. Instances are on various computers, one computer may host up to 4 instances.

A process is run on an instance via a bash shell :

```
process-on.sh <file_to_process> <instance_name>
```

`process-on.sh` knows how to access the instance (server, script-name, and so on) from the `instance_name`. The same unix client is used to run processes for all instances on one host, just the remote script name varies.

I would like instances act as a pool of processors, and want to use gnu-parallel as a distributor of files between instances.

I would like to use gnu-parallel, but it is mainly to distribute between computers, not isntances... Maybe there is another tool which can work with pools...

Any hints will be much appreciated.

Best,
Christophe

Answer (score 0):

You will need a way to convert a number into an instance - maybe some sort of lookup table.

```
instances=13
parallel -j$instances 'sleep 0.$RANDOM; echo this is file {} being processed on instance {%}' ::: {1..100}
```

Comment: I have such a way : my instance definition is a XML file, so I can access to instance by position.
Thanks a lot !